# Symbol: sideways a with cy) also sideways above.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My sister brought home some high school math today and I have no clue what the symbol means. It's a sideways a with a cy) above it (or to the right of it since I read left to write...). Anyone know what it could mean? 
[Image of math equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaG1L.jpg)

Thanks for any and all help!

Amy

Comment: This is not a math symbol, and is probably some typesetting/printing error. You should just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typo or a joke. In either case, it is a good exercise for your sister to figure out what possible values that symbol could have, assuming she only knows basic arithmetic and she only works with integers.

**Hint**: it has to be a multiple of 7, for example. Can it also be a multiple of 5? Etc.

Comment: I'll tell her to try and use it as a practice exercise, but that it's most likely a typo. Thank you. She is in grade 9 math, but it is not a strong subject for her and I cannot remember any more than basic math.... haha